# how i can find website visited list history in php?

Tags: php, ip-address

i want to get client IP address who uses my website. i am using php $_server super global

```
$_server['REMOTE_ADDER'];
```

but i see it cannot give the correct IP address

Answer (score 1):

It should be contained in the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable.

Comment: thanks its working fine...

Comment: welcome.Hope it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo mistake use below . The Pre Defined Variables in PHP are   Case sensitive should be used in UPPER CASE.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```